# How to update a specific field in all MongoDB documents from a string value to an array value

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongoDB collection contains 83,000+ documents which were imported from a .csv file. The schema is a simple, non-nested one.
Each document has a 'coordinates' field of type String which is like

```
coordinates: "61.11736,-149.86379"
```

I want to update/replace all of their values to be like:
`coordinates: [61.11736, -149.86379]` because I want to use the MongoDB $near query selector as it only works with fields of `type: 'Point'` with `<field_name>: [<long>, <lat>]`.

What sort of query should I run to perform this update?
(I'm using Node.js/Express).
Thanks in advance.

I basically want to make a query that will get places (which are MonogoDB documents) that are near a specified set of coordinates: [long, lat] but I'm not able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an update with an aggregate pipeline to make convert the field into a GeoJson point object.

```js
db.geoJson.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "coordinates": {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$reverseArray": {
                "$split": [
                  "$coordinates",
                  ","
                ]
              }
            },
            "as": "c",
            "in": {
              "$convert": {
                "input": "$$c",
                "to": "double",
                "onError": "",
                "onNull": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8uU_YAryG55)

Afterwards, you can create 2d sphere index on the field coordinates to perform the `$near` query you want.

Note that the coordinates are swapped to cater to Fix potential “longitude/latitude is out of bounds” error when creating the 2dsphere Index.

Ref: https://database.guide/fix-longitude-latitude-is-out-of-bounds-in-mongodb-when-creating-a-2dsphere-index/

Comment: It works. Thank you!
But something happened: MongoServerError: Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: Empty string.

The error came up because some docs had their coordinates field set to "", so the logic you wrote in the aggregation failed instantly when it encountered the first of such documents (whose 'coordinates'  is "").

The error prevented the rest of the documents' 'coordinates' from being transformed. Can you please help with that too?
Much thanks!

Comment: @Chima updated playground link to demonstrate usage of `$convert` to cater the empty values by `onError` and `onNull`. You can populate back those records with valid value later as the update will not block the operation anymore now.

Comment: I'm actually combining the query with a text search query:

 await Business.find({
      businessName: { $regex: `${textQuery}`, $options: 'i' },
      coordinates: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [+lat, +long] },
          $maxDistance: 1000,
        },
      },
 });

Gives an error:
error processing query: ns=LocalInspireDB.businessesTree: $and\n    businessName regex /restaur/i\n    GEONEAR  field=coordinates maxdist=1000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query

Comment: @Chima better not mix 2 problems together. You can ask a new question about putting the geoIndex and textIndex to work together and link back to this question for context. For this question, we can keep it clean and focused on geoIndex alone.